# Unity 3d how can I attach weapon to my character

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm a unity3d beginner and I have a problem about attaching a gun to my T-Pose character. Please answer how can I attach the gun to my t-pose character and use the gun in-game with seeing my character's hands.

Comment: Your question is way to broad for this site, go through [the tutorials on Unity's website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) to learn the basics, then once you try coding your self and you run in to a problem you can then bring your code examples here and ask for help.

Comment: Attach it to the hand bone of the model and position it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.

If you're using code, or an engine like UFPS, then you'd attach it with a gameobject.

If you want it to be part of the model/animation, you have to either acquire a model that has that already, or model it yourself.

I'd recommend that you search Google for it though, since it's more likely to have better answers for you.